# VBA compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment When trying to unmerge excel cells over multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro for the first time and came across a problem I did not manage to find an answer to online [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215022/unmerging-excel-rows-and-duplicate-data).
I have excel files with merged cells that I need to un-merge and then duplicate the value of the merged cell to all of the newly formed separated cells and then convert this file from .xslx to .csv.
I found a code that does exactly what I wish but the code is unmerging only the working Sheet (the sheet that I'm currently working on).
I tried putting this function in a loop through all the sheets, however, when I run the loop I get a compilation error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assingment"
I would be grateful for some insight as to why this is happening, how to solve it or any other idea for how to go about it.
Thanks

This is the function that I copied and it is working for one sheet

```
Public Sub UnMergeFill()

Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range

    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cell.MergeCells Then
            Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
            cell.MergeCells = False
            joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

this is the function I wrote and return the error

```
 Sub UnMergeFillAllSheets()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.Select
            Call UnMergeFill(ws)
        Next
    End Sub
```

the input is:
[[0][0][0][0]][1][1]

when the zeros are in one merged cell

the output:
[0][0][0][0][1][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Call UnMergeFill(ws)` is invoking the `UnMergeFill` procedure, passing in `ws` as an argument...

> ```
> Public Sub UnMergeFill()
> ```

...but the `UnMergeFill` procedure does not accept any parameters. Hence, "wrong number of arguments".

You need to change the signature of `UnMergeFill` to accept a `Worksheet` parameter:

```
Public Sub UnMergeFill(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
```

And then there's no need to `.Select` it anymore:

```
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        UnMergeFill ws
    Next
```

Except you now need `UnMergeFill` to work off the `Worksheet` parameter it's given:

```
For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
```

---

If you want `UnMergeFill` to still work off whatever the `ActiveSheet` is given no arguments, then you can make the parameter optional:

```
Public Sub UnMergeFill(Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet = Nothing)
```

...and then verify whether the procedure was invoked with a valid object reference:

```
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
```