# Unmerging excel rows, and duplicate data c#

Tags: c#, sql, excel, interop

This image show what i basically want to do

[image] [image: Unmerge excel rows and duplicate data with c#][image]

I have plenty excel files that i need to prepare before inserting the data into a SQL database, one of the steps is unmerge excel cells and duplicate the data, i'm doing this doc parse with c#
I found a solution with VBA Macro Excel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215022/unmerging-excel-rows-and-duplicate-data/28093448)

```
Sub UnMergeFill()
Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
        cell.MergeCells = False
        joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

But i need to do it on c# with microsoft.office.interop.excel 
Does anyone know if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# code is very similar:

```
    private void UnMergeFill(Workbook wb)
    {
        foreach (Range cell in ((_Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet).UsedRange)
        {
            if (cell.MergeCells)
            {
                var joinedCells = cell.MergeArea;
                cell.MergeCells = false;
                joinedCells.Value = cell.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```