# Excel Interop 0x800A03EC when setting UsedRange value

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-interop, powershell-5.1

Got partial code from [Unmerging excel rows, and duplicate data c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493386/unmerging-excel-rows-and-duplicate-data-c-sharp)

I'm converting Excel worksheets to CSV. Some cells are merged so I want to unmerge and copy that data, rather than lose it.

```
$Script:comExcelWB = $Script:comExcelApp.Workbooks.Open($TargetXlsxPath.FullName)
foreach ($Script:comExcelWS in $Script:comExcelWB.Worksheets) {
    if ($Script:comExcelWS.Visible) {
        $Script:comExcelWS.Select()
        foreach ($Script:comExcelRNG in $Script:comExcelWS.UsedRange) {
            if ($Script:comExcelRNG.MergeCells) {
                $Script:comExcelMA = $Script:comExcelRNG.MergeArea
                $Script:comExcelRNG.UnMerge()
                $Script:comExcelMA.Value = $Script:comExcelRNG.Value # Throws 0x800A03EC here
            }
        }
        $Script:comExcelWB.SaveAs("$($WSDestination.FullName)\$($Script:comExcelWS.Name).csv",
            [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSV, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode]::xlNoChange)
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

- [MergeArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.mergearea?view=excel-pia) states the property is [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range?view=excel-pia)
- [Range properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range?view=excel-pia#properties) shows two potential ways of setting the value:

  - [Value[Object]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value?view=excel-pia#microsoft-office-interop-excel-range-value(system-object)): The parameter is optional, and default appears to be what I want. Crashes as stated above.
  - [Value2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2?view=excel-pia#microsoft-office-interop-excel-range-value2): Remarks state that it's no different except for Current/Date types. Crashed as stated above on any data type.

Comment: The `0x3EC` part of the HRESULT likely refers to `JET_wrnColumnNull`, meaning `/* Column is NULL-valued */`

Comment: Some are NULL-valued for formatting/spacing, but, for instance, `A1:D1` is not NULL-valued. If we're saying it crashes because `$Script:comExcelRNG.Value` is NULL, that shouldn't be the case for `A1:D1`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it was related to NULL-value after all?

- Check range if it is `NULL`, continue setting if it isn't
- Use `Value2` and cast to `String` (to avoid `Double` -> `String` cast error)

```
$Script:comExcelWB = $Script:comExcelApp.Workbooks.Open($TargetXlsxPath.FullName)
foreach ($Script:comExcelWS in $Script:comExcelWB.Worksheets) {
    if ($Script:comExcelWS.Visible) {
        $Script:comExcelWS.Select()
        foreach ($Script:comExcelRNG in $Script:comExcelWS.UsedRange) {
            if ($Script:comExcelRNG.MergeCells) {
                $Script:comExcelMA = $Script:comExcelRNG.MergeArea
                $Script:comExcelRNG.UnMerge()
                                if ($null -ne $Script:comExcelMA.Value2) {
                                    $Script:comExcelMA.Value2 = [String]$Script:comExcelRNG.Value2
                                }
            }
        }
        $Script:comExcelWB.SaveAs("$($WSDestination.FullName)\$($Script:comExcelWS.Name).csv",
            [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSV, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode]::xlNoChange)
    }
}
```